# insert data in table 2 to table 1 with new id start with max from table 1

Tags: mysql

Here's my problem: I have two example tables below, where I tried inserting data from table two to table one with new id start from four.

I tried updating table two to change the auto increment and after that inserting to table one but it did not work.

Table 1

```
ID   DESC
1. 1    one
2. 2    two
3. 3    three
```

Table 2

```
ID   DESC
1. 1    four
2. 2    five
```

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_2 AUTO_INCREMENT = 4;
insert into table_1(id,desc)value('four','five');
```

Comment: What is that `ID` column?  Are the e.g. `1.` values just your own labels, or is that part of the `ID` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your code like this.

```
ALTER TABLE Table_2 AUTO_INCREMENT = 4;
insert into table_1(desc)values('four'),('five');
```

Answer (score 3):

Insert only `desc` to table 1

Example :

```
Insert into table_1(desc)
select desc from table_2
```

Answer (score 1):

When `table_1` **id field is an autoincrement value with the primary key**, it will add the next number to it.

Or you can do it by this

```
ALTER TABLE table_1 
MODIFY COLUMN 
ID INT auto_increment
```

So in query, you can do

```
INSERT INTO  table_1(desc)
VALUES ('four') ,('five');
```

---

When you create table like this, No issue occur like this

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    .......
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```